# What the diference between : the use of getContentPane() from JFrame Class & getContentPane() from JRootPane?

Tags: java, swing

I had done some research to understand the use of **JFrame**, and its **parts** and i find this info's:

**1- Parts of JFrame**

- Root Pane
- Menu Bare
- Content Pane
- Glass Pane

**2- JFrame implements  Interface RootPaneContainer**

```
return type  |  method name

Container       getContentPane();

Container       getGlassPane();

JLayeredPane    getLayeredPane();

JRootPane       getRootPane();
```

**3- JRootPane**
JRootPane of a JFrame. JRootPane is a lightweight container used behind    the scenes by JFrame.

JFrame implement the RootPaneContainer interface, and they all delegate their operations to a JRootPane.

**Note:** The JComponent method getRootPane can be used to obtain the   JRootPane that contains a given component.

**code :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        //--> create JFrame
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo Frame");
        f.setSize(300, 150);
        f.setVisible(true);

        //--> now use JFrame.getContentPane()

        Container c = f.getContentPane();

        //--> use JOptionpane.getContentPane()

        JRootPane op = f.getRootPane();
        op.getContentPane();         
    }
```

**Question :**  why i should use the method getContentPane() from  JRootPane instead of JFrame ?

Answer (score 2):

No difference. It is just more convenient to call `frame.getContentPane()` than `frame.getRootPane().getContentPane()`.

There are 2 reason why Swing does this way.

1) `JFrame` needs to implement `RootPaneContainer` as marker for reasons specified in [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RootPaneContainer.html).

2) It has separate `JRootPane` so that it can be reused in other RootPaneContainer implementing classes like `JDialor` and `JInternalFrame`. It is like [Delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer my help someone else :

**The interface RootPaneContainer** :

is implemented by components that have a single JRootPane child: JDialog, JFrame, JWindow, JApplet, JInternalFrame. **The methods in this interface are just covers for the JRootPane properties**,

**e.g. getContentPane() is generally implemented like this:**

```
 public Container getContentPane() {
     return getRootPane().getContentPane();
 }
```

**getRootPane();** return a JRootPane object

**getContentPanel();** return Container Object